# Interpreting VECM results

Tags: vector-error-correction-model

Can somebody help me interpreting this results for VECM? (`VAR.select` function chose 12 (or 1 and 2) as the appropriate number of lags, so I chose 11 lags)
How can I put below result in equation?
[image: vecm]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.